# Jenkinsfile with powershell. Need help dealing with quotes, triple-double-quotes and escaping characters

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Good day,

I've been struggling for a while dealing with triple-double-quotes, triple-single-quotes, escaping quotes...

I need to execute a Powershell command with quotes in it.

There is what I have:

```
testsDll = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '((Get-ChildItem -Path $env:WORKSPACE\\src\\Web\\*Unit.Tests.dll -Recurse) -join " ")').trim()

TestDllWithParameters = "$testsDll" + " /TestAdapterPath:" + "${env.WORKSPACE}" + "\\src\\Web\\packages\\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.16.1 /Logger:trx;LogFileName=Web123456.trx /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory!=DEADLOCK^&TestCategory!=QUARANTINE^&TestCategory!=Quarantine^&TestCategory!=NotImplemented^&TestCategory!=InProgress^&TestCategory!=INTEGRATION^&TestCategory!=Integration"
VSCodeExeFullPath =  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" 

env.VSTESTEXITCODE_WEB = powershell(returnStatus: true, script: """
   Start-Process "$VSCodeExeFullPath" -ArgumentList "$TestDllWithParameters" -NoNewWindow
""")'
```

Variable interpolation works. The problem I have is that I would like to keep the quotes around both `$VSCodeExeFullPath` and `$TestDllWithParameters` since both contains spaces.

Thank you!

Comment: [Neither double quotes nor single quotes need be escaped in triple-double-quoted strings.](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string). I only see one error, that is an excess `'` character at the end of your code sample.

Comment: Yeah there is no excess character in my original code sample... probably a leftover when I actually wrote this post. Even though there is no need to escape single and double quotes, it turns out I don't see those in my `Start-Process` statement. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: So what is the error you get? What is printed for the `powershell` step?

Comment: `Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null or empty.` Then I do a `Write-Host $TestDllWithParameters` and the variable is NOT empty... so weird!

Comment: What is the full command-line printed by the `powershell` step?

Comment: Could "${env.WORKSPACE}" be a typo try "${env:WORKSPACE}"

Comment: Try replacing  ArgumentList "$TestDllWithParameters" with ArgumentList $TestDllWithParameters

Comment: Running the command on a Powershell prompt was working but it wasn't when being executed from a ps1 file. You know what? It turns out changing the encoding has done the trick...! Thanks for your time buddy! Much appreciated!